# What command gives me the highlighted operator?

Tags: symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I need to write this equation in latex, but I don't know how to get the vertical line and the B subscript below it. If anyone knows the operator or command, it'd be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a structure `\left`-`\right`:

```
$\bar M_d = \left.\frac{d \bar H_B}{d t}\right|_B$
```

[image: Result of the code above]

Comment: `\left\vert...\right\vert` also produced the same result, but better spacing...

Comment: @MadyYuvi -- The code you show will produce two verticals; not what was requested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The code `$\left\vert \frac{a}{b}\right\vert$` will produce single vertical rule only, `\Vert` only produce two vertical lines...

Comment: @MadyYuvi -- That's not what I meant.  Only *one* vertical rule is requested, on only the right side.  That would be encoded, using your formulation, as `\left. ... \right\vert`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oops...I misunderstood....